# Expand DIV to page bottom when scrolling down

Tags: css, html, position, containers

On my site, I want to have a 'div' at the bottom of the page. It has no fixed height, but should always start '200px' from the top of the page.

The problem I am having is that when the content of the 'div' is very long, it's background doesn't expand when you scroll down.

Here is my code: [JSFiddle (updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/HMxkr/8/)

I have tried working with `height=auto` and `border=auto`, but then the 'div' doesn't stretch to the page bottom when there is less content and you don't have to scroll down.

**Update**:

Sorry for miss expressing my problem: I need the 'div' to have `position: relative` because I need it to be positioned in the center of the page with `left=10%` and `right=10%`.

I also updated the JSFiddle.

**Update 2**:

I guess there is no perfect solution to this problem. What I will end up doing: Having two 'divs'. The first div will have the page content on it and will not show the background when there is less content; the other div will be behind the content-div and won't scroll at all, but it will show the background for the div in front when there is less content.

Comment: Try using `overflow: hidden` or `overflow:scroll`.

Comment: @helderdarocha I don't want to hide the text not displayed without scrolling down, neither I want to have an extra scroll bar in the page. I want the 200px above the div to disappear when scrolling down.

Comment: is very long or isn't very long? Because if it is long, then it should expand. See your own fiddle. It does to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed some 'design' from your original to be able to satisfy your requirement.

First, here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxN9L/)

```
#top {
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
}
body {
    background:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

What I've done is I've set the whole page background to red. Made the #top height 200px with white background, so the #bottom would be 200px apart from the top. Now the trick I've done is, the #bottom is actually isn't touching the bottom if it has less content, but what you see is the illusion from the body's background and #bottom's no background.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to position relative will work in your example fiddle.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning before that I can't change it to position:relative. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

add `height: auto;` to your div's css

**EDIT:**
and remove `bottom: 0;`

Comment: That will not work when there is only a few lines of text in the div, because I want it stretch to the bottom of the page.